# How to add a button widget to a rectangle canvas in Android?

Tags: android

Hi, I want to develop a form on a rectangle.

I have designed a rectangle using a bitmap and an image, but how do I add edit texts and buttons onto that?

Please provide some good guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout inside your main layout with background as your bitmap image.
Then put your widgets inside this inner layout.
When you place your widgets be sure that it is coming correctly in all screen sizes. 
For that try to avoid manually setting pixel values.
Use dp instead.
Also use layout properties of relative layout.